# Coilcraft model pin 1

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, footprint

In the two images and [linked model description](https://www.coilcraft.com/getmedia/fe569a42-533f-4322-ab3b-764883f54979/fct1xxm22sl.pdf), am I incorrect, or did they place the pin 1 indicator incorrectly? It should be bottom right, from the top view.
Edit:
seems their photo for the model has the pin 1 bottom right, and the 3d model has to be incorrect.
[image: Footprint][image: 3D Model]
[image]

Comment: What part number are you actually designing for. The datasheet for [FCT1-50M2SL](https://www.coilcraft.com/getmedia/bf4978d0-9594-4a1a-9b68-3fd2d65bb8f1/fct1xxm2sl.pdf) shows pin numbering matching your 2nd image. But this is a 15 W part, and the datasheet you linked to is for a series of 25 W parts.

Comment: It's a bit odd that they made these two series have incompatible footprints. It may be worth calling Coilcraft to confirm the footprint of whichever one you are using.

Comment: I got this model via email from coilcraft for the design. Thanks. I will ask them again, as I asked already about the footprints.

Comment: For which part number? The one you linked the datasheet for, or the one written on the part in the image?

Comment: They gave me the model for use with FCT2-50M2SL. I understand why its wrong now, the footprints don't match between the series of 25W and 15W transformers. They should not have provided this model for this footprint. Just confused me last night.